# What is CTRL-W Tab doing?

Tags: key-bindings, tags, ctags, filetype-c++

By pure coincidence, I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> and then <kbd>Tab</kbd> while editing a C++ file, and what happened is that the window was horizontally split and the new window loaded the buffer where the word under the entity was presumably defined.

I can reproduce this behavrior even with `vim -Nu NONE thatfile.cpp`.

Then I tried the same with the cursor on `std::cout`, but that gave me a [E387](https://vimhelp.org/tagsrch.txt.html#E387), which at least led me to a seemingly relevant [documentation page](https://vimhelp.org/tagsrch.txt.html), but that page has no match for the regex `\cctrl-w.*\_..*tab`, so I assume I'm in the wrong place.

On the other hand, that page seems to describe something similar to what I'm observing, even if it associates it to another combo:

> To split the current window and jump to the tag under the cursor use this
> command:
>
> ```
>                           CTRL-W ]
> ```

But with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>,<kbd>]</kbd> I get [E433](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#E433) and [E426](https://vimhelp.org/tagsrch.txt.html#E426) if my cursor is on `std::cout`, for instance.

To be precise, the jump is not exactly accurate. If I'm on `filter` on last line, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> leads me to [`/usr/include/meta/meta.hpp`](https://github.com/ericniebler/meta/blob/master/include/meta/meta.hpp), whereas it should bring me to [`/usr/include/range/v3/view/filter.hpp`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/include/range/v3/view/filter.hpp), as [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/) does.

So, what am I seeing?

Answer (score 2):

For historic reasons, `<Tab>` and `<C-i>` are indistinguishable in Vim (look up the ASCII table). When you pressed `<C-w><Tab>`, you actually pressed `<C-w><C-i>`, which is described under `:help ctrl-w_ctrl-i`:

> Open a new window, with the cursor on the first line that contains the keyword under the cursor.

which is part of the larger `:help include-search` feature.

The errors you get are pretty much self-explanatory if you know that you are using include search:

- `E387: Match is on current line`

  It probably means a) that Vim didn't find includes or b) that it found includes but didn't find the keyword under the cursor in them.

or tag search:

- `E433: No tags file`

  Vim didn't find a `tags` file at the expected location (see `:help 'tags'`).
- `E426: Tag not found: foo`

  Therefore it couldn't find a tag for the keyword under the cursor.

The "`<Tab>` is `<C-i>`" business is mentioned under `:help <Tab>`. Both tag search and include search are quite thoroughly explained in chapter 29 of the user manual: `:help usr_29`. *Poking Vim at random has always been a losing strategy. Don't.*

Comment: Well, was actually an unintentionally mistaken keystroke :D